# How do I Find Preparatory Exposure?

Tags: soft-question, education

I always prefer to be prepared ahead of time, but I am not
sure of how to be for a career in mathematics. How do I immerse myself in a formal, mathematical environment
without necessarily enrolling in a university, and at the
same time take a general survey of the profession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking one of the free pdf textbooks that are available online, and doing exercises / proofs on the first few pages.

A career (in research mathematics) is not exactly described by this, but it provides the same idea you would have gotten from university.

Just know that actually doing research mathematics might be a lot more undirected than following an exam book. To really know what that's like, you should look at some issue or other that you're interested in, and trying to prove things about it, without following some predefined structure.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. How do I acclimate myself to the use of mathematical formalism?

Comment: @ArnoldSharp acclimatization is through exposure, yes? Force yourself to be formal. If you don't know what the formalities are, try to read some proofs. Youtube seldom proves things, and there are numerous papers online. Just be careful that you start with easy stuff, like basic number theory.